# Having trouble understanding the @ parameter in a SQL command

Tags: vb.net

Good morning,

I am having trouble understanding the @ parameter in vb.net. if we take the example code for the msdn:

```
    ' Update the demographics for a store, which is stored 
    ' in an xml column.
    Dim commandText As String = _
     "UPDATE Sales.Store SET Demographics = @demographics " _
     & "WHERE CustomerID = @ID;"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(commandText, connection)

        ' Add CustomerID parameter for WHERE clause.
        command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
        command.Parameters("@ID").Value = customerID

        ' Use AddWithValue to assign Demographics.
        ' SQL Server will implicitly convert strings into XML.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demographics", demoXml)
```

There seem to be no problem at all, however when you try to add more parameters into the mix, it does not seems to work. What would be the correct syntax to add more than one parameter?

Here is my piece of code:

```
    query &= "INSERT INTO "
    query &= imageProcAlgo.GetSqlTable()
    query &= " ( @dateTimeStampCol , @numberOfBlobsCol , @AvgLengthCol , @avgWidthCol ) "
    query &= "Values (@dtsvalue, @nbOfBlobsValue, @avgLengthValue, @avgWidthValue)"
```

and here where I try to add values to those parameters:

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection(connectStr)

    Using comm As New SqlCommand(query)
        With comm
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTimeStampCol", "DateTimeStamp")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@numberOfBlobsCol", "NumberOfBlob")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvgLengthCol", "AvgWidth")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@avgWidthCol", "AvgLength")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtsvalue", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@nbOfBlobsValue", imageProcAlgo.GetnumberOfBlobs().ToString())
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@avgLengthValue", imageProcAlgo.GetAvgWidth())
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@avgWidthValue", imageProcAlgo.GetAvgLength())


        End With
        Try
            conn.Open()
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
        End Try
    End Using
```

When I try to execute this piece of code, I get an error saying that @datetimestampcol and so on are not valid column names.

I don't seem to understand what is the difference between the MSDN anf my code but i feel pretty close.. Any pointers for me to understand a bit better? to figure out where I went wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Parameters come "after" the VALUES keyword.  Everything before that has to be an existing field name.

Comment: `@datetimestampcol and so on are not valid column names`, in your `sql` you need to type your column names in the insert into statement, you are trying to use parameters, this wont work...

Comment: I see, that seem to do the trick indeed. Thank you very much.